# angularjs submit button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I'm validating & submitting a simple form using angularjs, the form seems to do some initial validation but the submit button does not log or executes the angular function defined to it. What am I doing wrong?

Main app.js

```
var quora=angular.module("quora-app",['q-controller-1','ngRoute']);
quora.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/edit',{
            templateUrl:'../resources/views/forms/edit.blade.php',
            controller:'q-master-1'
        });
});
```

Controller

```
angular.module("q-controller-1",[])
    .controller("q-master-1",['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.update=function(value,text) {
            $scope.id=value;
            $scope.putText=text;
        }
        $scope.validate=function(updateInfo) {
            console.log(updateInfo);
            if($scope.update.$valid) {
                $scope.test1=$scope.id
                $scope.test2=$scope.updateInfo.qText
            }
            else
                console.log("no")
        }
    }]);
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form name="update" method="POST" action="edit.blade.php" ng-submit="validate(updateInfo);" onsubmit="return false;" >
    <b ng-show="update.question.$dirty && update.question.$error.required">Invalid</b>
    <input type="text" name="question" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3" ng-value="putText" ng-model="updateInfo.qText">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" ng-show="update.$valid">
</form>
```

File where execution initiates

```
@{{ test1 }}
@{{ test2 }}
@section('list-questions-answers')
    <div ng-view></div>
    <ul>
        @foreach($listQuestionsAnswers as $q)
            <li>
                <a href="{{url('/questions/'.$q->question_id)}}">{{ $q->question }}</a>
                Options: <a href="#edit" ng-click="update({{ $q->question_id }},'{{ $q->question }}')">Edit</a>
            </li>
            @foreach($q->answers as $a)
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ $a->answer }}</li>
                </ul>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

The `ng-view` is being loaded, but the submit button is not working or logging anything!

Comment: Try removing onsumbit attribute !

Comment: then it will submit like a normal form, which is of no use !

Comment: You can do one thing don't go for native approach . Instead remove ng-submit and on submit , action post and all that , and just add ng-click to the submit button and use ng-disabled to disable submit button until the form is valid like you are doing now

Comment: I suspect the culprit is your action attribute which is trying to do a post call which is out of Angular context , try removing that you don't need such native things when working with Angular

Comment: Did it work ? What changes you made ?

Comment: yes, had to only remove `action`

Comment: cool should I post it as answer if that helped you ?

Comment: sure! as u like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the issue was with `action` attribute in the form tags as it works well with the native forms but when working with Angular that behaviour doesn't comply.

As angular is trying to call the ng-submit function but the action method is trying to process the request URL.

**Alternative approach:**

Instead remove `ng-submit` and `on submit` , `action` `post` and all that , and just add `ng-click` to the submit button and use `ng-disabled` to disable submit button until the form is valid.

Comment: @Jaskaran can you accept this as answer,it would help others also!